# Create a function to generate a column value in a specific format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I am new to databases or, in fact, programming. I want to create a function or maybe a stored procedure (if it works) to insert/create default values for a column of the *users* table. In this table, each of the registered users should be assigned a *userId* like `K16060600`, the format being `Kyymmddxx`, where

- `K` is constant for every *userId*,
- `yy` stands for year (e.g. `16` for 2016),
- `mm` stands for month,
- `dd` stands for day,
- `xx` is a number for 00 to 99 and it should increment from 00 whenever a new row/user is added.
- It is guaranteed that I will add fewer than 100 each day.

How can I do that?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way would be to add an `ID` column in your users table, with a default value based on a sequence object, then add a computed column to create the key using a date conversion to string.

To create the sequence, something like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[userid_sq] 
 AS [int]
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 1
 MINVALUE 1
 MAXVALUE 500
 CYCLE
```

I wouldn't limit yourself to a value of 99 if you are not 100% sure you are going to stay under that number of users per day.

You want a fresh cycle every day, right? So you can force it with an evening job/script to ensure it is back at 1 the next day.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE [dbo].[userid_sq]  RESTART WITH 1;
```

So just to illustrate the point, say I'm creating a new table, `UserDetails`, and want to include this logic, I might do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE UserDetails (
    ID INT NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR userid_sq
    ,Created DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
    ,UserKey AS 
        'K' + 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), Created, 12) + 
        RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), 1000 + ID), 3)
    ,UserName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO UserDetails (UserName)
VALUES ('TestUser')
```

My table content would be:

```
ID       - 1
UserKey  - K160531001
UserName - TestUser
```

You asked about indexing, so, ignoring the fact that the above example would be non-deterministic and therefore ineligible to be used a primary key, if you want to index the computed column, you'll need to PERSIST the column in the database. This stores the values to disk rather than as a calculated virtual value.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN computed_column_name ADD PERSISTED;
```

Note that there are various restrictions with what you can do with computed columns so I would implore you to read the following information to get a proper understanding.

[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188300.aspx)

Here's a relevant snippet from that article, which also relates to the above example:

> A computed column cannot be used as a DEFAULT or FOREIGN KEY constraint definition or with a NOT NULL constraint definition. However, if the computed column value is defined by a deterministic expression and the data type of the result is allowed in index columns, a computed column can be used as a key column in an index or as part of any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint. For example, if the table has integer columns a and b, the computed column a + b may be indexed, but computed column a + DATEPART(dd, GETDATE()) cannot be indexed, because the value might change in subsequent invocations.
>
> A computed column cannot be the target of an INSERT or UPDATE statement.

Comment: I code works welk except that everyday it updates the userkeys on database. I dnt understand how but as date chancges it updates userkey. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Thanks I just saw that, and hiw would I use the userkey as primary key?

Comment: Thanks I have checked it out, and when I add persisted its says userkey cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that would be because it's using the field Created which is using the getdate() function.

Comment: I noticed that after reading more non-deterministic functions, so but is there no other way I can use to generate these userkeys?

Comment: Well I will keep working it Mayb I will findd something as...but how good/bad it can be if I generate these userkeys in the app code and then insert into a database

Comment: Generating key in the app code, then inserting into the database, with key going into indexed column would be something interesting to explore...